# Forum submit button is redirecting me to an unknown webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a "contact us" forum with html.

This is my current html:

```
<form id="contact_form" name="contact_form" method="post" action="validate()">
    <div class="row">
        <label for="name" class="desc" style="font-size: 30px;">Your name:</label><br />
        <input id="name" class="input" name="name" type="text" value="" size="50" /><br />
    </div><br /><br />
    <div class="row">
        <label for="email" class="desc" style="font-size: 30px;">Your email:</label><br />
        <input id="email" class="input" name="email" type="text" value="" size="50" /><br />
    </div><br /><br />
    <div class="row">
        <label for="message" class="desc" style="font-size: 30px;">Your message:</label><br />
        <textarea id="message" class="input" name="message" rows="8" cols="50"></textarea><br />
    </div>
    <div class="row"><br />
    <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Send email"/>
    </div>
    </form>
```

And my javascript:

```
function validate() {
    //Make sure name is filled out
    var x = document.forms["contact_form"]["name"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    //Make sure email is filled out
    var x = document.forms["contact_form"]["email"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Email must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    //Make sure message is filled out
    var x = document.forms["contact_form"]["message"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Message must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    //Validate email
    var x = document.forms["contact_form"]["email"].value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos< 1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
        alert("Not a valid email");
        return false;
    }

}
```

For some reason when I hit "submit" it takes me to a page called "validate()" How can I make it so that when I click submit it EXECUTES the function validate(), not just take me to a page called validate()...

NOTE: Nevermind the php, right now focus on the html and javascript

Comment: BECAUSE action="validate()"

Comment: `onsubmit="return validate();"`. But consider learning other ways of binding event handlers: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It redirects it to that page because you are setting the action to go there. That does not execute JavaScript. You are looking for onsubmit.

Change `action="validate()"` to `onsubmit="return validate();"`

And as always, it would be better to set it unobtrusively instead of inline.